# Calling 1 function to produce 2 different 2D arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void generate_matrices(int a[5][5], int b[5][5]);
void print_matrix(int a[5][5]);
void multiply_matrices(int a[5][5], int b[5][5], int c[5][5]);
void calc_trace(int a[5][5]);

int main()
{
    int a[5][5],b[5][5];
    generate_matrices(a,b);
    print_matrix(a);

    return 0;
}

void generate_matrices(int a[5][5], int b[5][5])
{
    int seed,i,j;
    printf("Enter seed integer value: ");
    scanf("%d",&seed);
    printf("\n\nSeed Value is %d\n\n",seed);
    srand(seed);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
            a[i][j]=rand() %51 + (-25);
            b[i][j]=rand() %51 + (-25); }
    }
}

void print_matrix(int a[5][5])  {

    int i,j;
    printf("Matrix A:\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
            printf("%d  ",a[i][j]); }
    printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nMatrix B:\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
            printf("%d  ",a[i][j]); }
    printf("\n");
    }

}
```

This is a piece of code I have. The `generate_matrices` function works fine, however the function I need help on is the `print_matrix` function. I need to call this function twice and have it produce 2 different arrays. Currently I have the a[i][j] called twice in the function, however my second a[i][j] needs to be a b[i][j].

The problem is, I don't understand how you can have 1 function called to produce 2 different arrays? If I haven't made it clear enough, e.g:

```
(...)

    print_matrix(a)
    print_matrix(b)

(...)


void print_matrix(int a[5][5])
{
(...)
}
```

So the i'm calling the same function twice to print 2 different arrays, however I don't understand how you can call the function the first time to produce only 1 array, then calling the same function again with a different variable to produce the second array? Surely calling the function the first time would produce everything created in the function itself???

FYI: I  cannot change function names, or create pointers in function names etc.

I hope I've made it relatively clear, cheers.

Comment: Sorry, but :facepalm: Print only one matrix in this function (remove the part beginning with `printf("matrix B");`) and call it two times with two different matrices. If you want the name of the matrix to be displayed, pass it as another option to `print_matrix`

Comment: Relatively clear :) Not at all clear...

Comment: change your prototype `void print_matrix(int a[5][5], int b[5][5])`

Comment: Are you confusing the variable name and the variable content ? You must learn basics about C.

Comment: Sorry i'm not all wizards like you, had some extra work to do so heads been all over the place....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn this section of code :

```
    void print_matrix(int a[5][5])  {

    int i,j;
    printf("Matrix A:\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
            printf("%d  ",a[i][j]); }
        printf("\n");
        }
    printf("\nMatrix B:\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
            printf("%d  ",a[i][j]); }
    printf("\n");
    }

}
```

into this :

```
void print_matrix(int a[5][5])  {

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){   //removed matrix dependent line
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
            printf("%d  ",a[i][j]); }
        printf("\n");
        }                 //removed the bottom section of code.

}
```

then in main you call it like so:

```
int main()
{
    int a[5][5],b[5][5];
    generate_matrices(a,b);
    printf("Matrix A:\n");   // tells you which matrix
    print_matrix(a);    // Pass in matrix a
    printf("Matrix B:\n");  // tells you which matrix
    print_matrix(b);  // Pass in matrix b
    return 0;
}
```

This will print each matrix independently of each other. This can be further extended to N matrices by changing which matrix you pass into the `print_matrix()' function.

Comment: Thank you, knew it would be something as simple as this, cheers!!